# managing 'deprecated' warnings in Android project with minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, lint

I hate warnings. Our Android project has 151 now, and I am sure that somewhere down the list there is one that actually warns us against a potential trouble.

One type of these warnings is about deprecated fields and methods. This could be useful, except that the Manifest contains `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`, and these warnings only take into account the `target` SDK which is `android-17`.

It's easy to mute these warnings - add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation before the offending line, or the whole method. But this misses the whole point of it - if/when we decide to change `minSdkVersion="11"`, the APIs that are deprecated at level 10 will still not show up, and somebody will have to go through all annotations in all our project, to find which code must be rewritten.

Is there some solution that could manage these warnings based on my **minSdkVersion**?

---

It seems that [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) who posted an interesting answer below, and even [filed a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53389) inspired by my question does not agree with me about the importance of **minSdkVersion**. He would prefer to see deprecation warnings (most likely from Lint, similar to the `@TargetApi(NN)` annotations) based on the target API level. But I cannot agree with this approach.

Consider a simple application that opens the Camera. It might want to check the [preview frame rate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPreviewFrameRate()). But this method was deprecated at API 9, and now we must check the [preview FPS range](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPreviewFpsRange()). If we use `platforms/android-8/android.jar`, the Java compiler will not show deprecation warnings.

But it will not allow us to find the [preferred video resolution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()), even in case the application is running on a device that supports such query. We will probably add `@TargetApi(11)` annotation there, to make sure the application is built with `platforms/android-11/android.jar` or higher.

Now that we have target **Honeycomb** and higher, the deprecation warning will be shown for <strike>getPreviewFrameRate()</strike>, and this is exactly what bothers me. For a while, my imaginary application must support some **Froyo** devices, therefore I have no choice but set `minSdkVersion=8` and use the deprecated method. Naturally, I will use any advanced APIs in conditional blocks, and have the `@TargetApi(NN)` in place. *Luckily, for **Donut** and higher, the class loader does not crash when a call to a non-existent method or member is detected, and wrapping the questionable calls in mere **if()** is enough.*

So what do I do? Add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` around the calls to <strike>getPreviewFrameRate()</strike> to mute the warnings? Add `@SuppressDeprecation(8)` instead?

But at some point, I will decide that the backward compatibility with Froyo is not important anymore. I set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />` in my Manifest, but the deprecation warnings for <strike>getPreviewFrameRate()</strike> are still suppressed... Well, the new approach is definitely better than the existing annotation, because it's easier to `grep -R "@SuppressDeprecation(8)"` the whole project after the change is made in Manifest.

But I would prefer a bit more tight integration here: let Lint parse the Manifest file for me.

Does this make better sense now?

Comment: Check if you documentation is the same version as the sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a feature request for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41318 filed on Dec 12, 2012.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there some solution that could manage these warnings based on my minSdkVersion?

No, because deprecation has nothing to do with `android:minSdkVersion`.

If you are really worried about this, isolate the deprecated stuff into their own methods, to minimize the odds that your annotation will obscure future deprecations of which you are unaware.

What's not completely out of the question would be a `@SuppressDeprecation(NN)` annotation, that would suppress deprecations for a given build target. This would be akin to how `@TargetApi(NN)` suppresses Lint complaints for a given `android:minSdkVersion`. I have [filed a feature request for this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53389).

Comment: I would trade the Java depreciation checking for Lint checks, but it is really important to have their level in sync with minSdkVersion

Comment: @AlexCohn: I repeat: deprecation has to do with build target, not `minSdkVersion`. Your claims in your second-to-last paragraph make no sense to me. Changing `minSdkVersion` changes nothing about what is or is not deprecated.

Comment: Cool... we have a discussion here! Since SO format does not encourage long chains of comments, I will expand my argumentation in the main question section.